# Where do I download .bst files for bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

This should be a basic question, but my search engine is failing me.  Where do I go to download .bst files for LaTeX/bibtex?

Precise format is flexible but I want something that will work with natbib and author-year formats, and that can gracefully handle urls as @misc entries.

Comment: Try http://lmgtfy.com/?q=bst+bibtex+ctan (not totally serious)

Answer (score 10):

more than 150 bst files are already on your TeX-distribution. You can browse that directory, which can easily be found by running

```
kpsewhich plain.bst
```

e.g. for Linux and TeXLive:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/plain.bst
```

For Windows open a command window (Start->cmd) and run the command.

For my system all known bst-files are in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/
```